# xml engine for multiple service provider

Tags: .net, xml, soap, rule-engine

With real examples and their use, can someone please help me understand:

1. How to integrating multiple xml/soap service provider?
2. How to mapp the data with different provider?

Comment: You need to be way more specific

Comment: Actually we are integrating around 5 service providers for airline, hotel. each and every provider having there different xml/soap format for request as well as response. and what i need is to handle all request/response with a standard format. or otherwise how would i handle this simultaneously? and also the static data every provider provides may vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a Business rules engine named Drools-3.0 for for business rule.

[drools engine](http://www.jboss.org/drools)